# Chapter title format is too wide

Tags: formatting, chapters, titles

I have the problem that my chapter title is too wide, because it has the same width like the line below. How can I change the width from the title? For example, when you uncomment the `\geometry{...}` lines, it works but not much enough. AND why are the two lines not directly among each other (e.g. the two left "T"'s)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    left=3cm,
    right=3cm
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\relax}{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{10pt}%
{\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%


\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test title Test title Test title Test title Test title Test title }
\end{document}
```

Title:

[image]

I wan't this, but with variable/more space between chapter title and right end (result by uncomment the geometry, but that is not the solution because I need it)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but are you aware that you can have `\chapter[short]{long long long}`?

Comment: No, this results only changing the chapter title in TOC, if I'm right with this command.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable/more space"? You could put the actual title in a minipage, of say `0.9\linewidth` like this `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\relax}{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{10pt}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\end{minipage}\linebreak\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]` Or do you want where it wraps to depend on the width of the number?

Comment: No, that is what I want. But now the horizontal line is too close to the title. The baselineskip command doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Sorry, it's ok so. Problem solved!